# Why it is not allowed to create datetime constant in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a datetime constant in .net but getting the error message

```
const DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("02/02/2014");
```

'System.DateTime' cannot be declared const.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a constant?

Comment: In VB.NET: `Const today As DateTime = #2/25/2013#`

Comment: I, too, would need a DateTime const, for use in parameterized  Unit Tests, for instance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

DateTime is not a native type in the C# language - it's a struct from the .Net libraries.

In C#, you can only create consts from the native language types, and you can only initialise them with values that can be calculated at compile-time. DateTime.Now cannot be calculated at compile time.

(The only reference type you can use with a const is a string, and that's because strings are handled specially.)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I'll also add that `DateTime.Now` is not a `const` expression in itself. Const values can only be assigned to from other const expressions, such as literals.

Comment: Thanks, updated to include that and something about strings too.

Answer (score 32):

Even if you *could* declare a `DateTime` as const (which you can't, as other answers have indicated) you would have to use a *compile-time constant* as the value - and `DateTime.Now` most certainly isn't a compile-time constant.

This is valid though:

```
static readonly DateTime dt = DateTime.Now();
```

Note that this will be "whatever time the type initializer for the type ran" though. That's rarely a particularly useful value unless you ensure it's initialized on start-up, assuming that's what you're trying to measure...

Comment: Good point about being able to use readonly as an alternative to const.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `VB.NET` `Const` will also be translated to `static readonly` at compile time. So this is  just a pseudo constant: `Const today As DateTime = #2/25/2013#`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Only for values which can't be represented using `literal` in IL. If you use `Public Const Bar As Integer = 20` that ends up as `.field public static literal int32 Bar = int32(0x14)` in IL.

Comment: it means we can't create constant for structures.

Comment: @Romil: I don't know how to interpret your comment. `Int32` is a structure, for example - other than `string`, *every* type there's a literal form for in C# is a structure. You can't create constants for your own user-defined structures, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: DateTime.MinValue seems like a pretty obvious constant to me. The below answer about this just being a failing of the .Net Framework is the better explanation.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Better explanation for what? I didn't particularly *try* to explain why `DateTime` values can't be `const` in C#... I was mostly pointing out a) that `DateTime.Now` isn't reasonably a compile-time constant anyway, and that b) *because* you can't use `DateTime` values as constants, using a static readonly field is the closest you'll get.