# Why DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.MaxValue are not const

Tags: c#

Why `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` are not const like `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`? Why would `C#` do that?

I tried to take a look at `struct DateTime` but couldn't find any constructor that initializes these fields.

Comment: Are they different in the same version of .NET? Under what circumstances are they different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C# limit the set of types that can be declared as const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441420/why-does-c-sharp-limit-the-set-of-types-that-can-be-declared-as-const)

Comment: Only native types can be constants. [Why it is not allowed to create datetime constant in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063431/why-it-is-not-allowed-to-create-datetime-constant-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET only primitive types and strings can be constants.

> I tried to take a look at struct DateTime but couldn't find any constructor that initializes these fields.

They are initialized in place:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,114

In practice, initialization of static fields will be generated in the static constructor:[image]

**Fun fact**:

In C# you can define `decimal` constants; however, `decimal` is not a primitive type. In the background these "constants" will also be compiled as static fields with a special `DecimalConstant` attribute:
[image]

Comment: It might be worth modifying your first sentence to mention decimal, given that the later part contradicts it. It's also worth noting that there's a [`DateTimeConstantAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.datetimeconstantattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) that *could* be used in the same way if C# ever wanted to support them.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I corrected the first sentence. And I did not know about the `DateTimeConstantAttribute`, thank you for the info.